# Inside a UITabBarController how do I segue from one view controller to another and retain the tab bar?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I drag a UITabBarController from Object library to the storyboard.
From firstViewController I want to swipe to another viewController named CustomController using a swipe gesture recognizer and retain the tab bar on CustomController when it is instantiated.
The problem is that once the segue is performed from firstViewController to CustomController, the tab bar no longer shows at the bottom of Custom Controller and it does not swipe back to firstViewController.

This is the outcome I would like to achieve. Please advise best route.

[image]

Comment: According to your picture is segment not tabbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use **ContainerView** to view your view controller. when you
>   click on segment 1 you can set your **firstviewcontroller** to
>   **containerview** and when you click on segment 2 you need to replace **customviewcontroller** in **containerview**. you do like this you will not lose your tab bar **viewcontroller**. For Swipe gesture, you
>   can add it later if you want. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would appreciate if you could write some code since this seems to be a very common issue and other users will find it helpful.

Comment: If possible you can send me your source code. I will complete that function.

Comment: this is my starter project https://github.com/bibscy/someTestTab  . Please use the segmented Control in order to obtain the same behaviour as in the picture. I didn't know about "Semented Control" till you told me.

Comment: Ok, let me check it.

Comment: The UISwipeGestureRecognizer recognizer is missing. Could you please post your answer and explanation of what you did there in the answer section. The google drive link will go down, but your answer will remain here on SO forever. When you put the answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147666/discussion-between-sour-leangchhean-and-bibscy).